# How to export current search page to csv in rails 3/4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

In rail 3/4, exporting to csv can be done by defining method `self.to_csv` in model and add `format.csv` to `respond_to` in controller. A click to `link_to "CSV", index_path(format: "csv")` start exporting. The exporting calls the same action again and render in csv.

Our question is how a use can export current page to csv. A user may start searching, then decide to export the current page to csv (without redo the search for csv exporting). Is there a way a user can do so?

UPDATE:
example of controller code for csv exporting:

```
  #for csv download
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {@query = @query.page(params[:page]).per_page(30)}
    format.csv do
      send_data @query.to_csv
      @csv = true
    end
  end
```

Here is the example of self.to_csv in model:

```
def self.to_csv
      CSV.generate do |csv|
        #header array
        header = ['id', 'action', 'resource', 'brief_note', 'last_updated_by_id', 'role_definition_id', 'sql_code', 'masked_attrs', 'rank', 'created_at', 'updated_at']        
        csv << header
        all.each do |config|
          #assembly array for the row
          .....
          #inject to csv
          csv << row
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your page is taking into account a search parameters (let say a @query variable) in the controller, you could simply call back the exact same controller, but asking for CSV format instead of HTML.

Let's suppose you are listing users in a /users routes, and have a search parameter such as:

```
/users?query=smith
```

You could create a link to generate:

```
/users.csv?query=smith
```

This will call back the same controller, just changing the format. This could be done using code like:

```
link_to "CSV", index_path(format: "csv", :query => @query)
```

Comment: @@Martin, how can I retrieve @query in self.to_csv when generating csv? Do I need to add a variable .to_csv as self.to_csv(query)?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without having your controller's code (just the index method) - could you post it here?

Comment: Just posted controller and model code. Use @query instead for convenience. Thanks.